# Achive a "more than 10 connections, pass to next server" setup with NGINX or other

Tags: nginx, haproxy

**Idea**

Gradually use a few small-scale dedicated servers in combination with an expensive cloud platform, where - on little traffic - the dedicated servers should first filled up before the cloud kicks in. Hedging against occasional traffic spikes.

**nginx**

Is there an easy way (without nginx plus) to achieve a "waterfall like" set-up, where small servers should first be served up to a maximum number of concurrent connections, or better, current bandwidth before the cloud platform sees any traffic?

Nginx Config, Libraries, Tools?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You will use nginx [`upstream`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html) module.

If you want total control, set your cloud servers with `backup` parameter, so that they won't be used until your primary servers fail. Then use custom monitoring scripts to determine when those could servers should kick-in, change nginx config and remove the `backup` keyword from them. Also monitor conditions when you want to stop using the cloud servers and alter the nginx config.

More simple solution (but without fine tuning like avoiding spikes) is to use the `max_conns=number` parameter. Nginx should start to use the backup server if all other already have max number of connections (I didn't test it).

NOTE: `max_conns` parameter was only available in paid nginx between v1.5.9 and v1.11.5, so the only solution with these versions is own monitoring + reloading of nginx config when needed to change the upstream servers. Thanks Mickaël Le Baillif's comment to point out this parameter is now available to all.

Comment: Is max_conns part of open source nginx?

Comment: @DinoScheidt, sorry it's not. I haven't noticed it. Then your only solution with nginx is own monitoring script and reloading nginx config.

Comment: `max_conns` is actually available for everyone, not just for commercial subscriptions, since version 1.11.5, as stated on the [`upstream` documentation page](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html) :

    "Since version 1.5.9 and prior to version 1.11.5, this parameter was available as part of our commercial subscription."